# Xcode 7 code coverage - No Coverage Data

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, xcode7

I have ticked "Gather coverage data" and run the unit test, however Xcode shows "**No Coverage Dat**".

All Unit test are passed.
Xcode 7 is used

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Need to tick "Show Test Bundle"

Comment: Yes, it did work. See my second picture, top right, there is "Show Test Bundle".

Comment: That seems to show how much of your test bundle is being run, not the App under test.

Comment: You need to do this if testing a library, loadable bundle or standalone executable. Otherwise (for Cocoa apps), the tests will already be showing.

Comment: i had the same issue after enabling "Show Test Bundle" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Edit Scheme > Test > Info > check mark Code Coverage

**Don't forget to choose Editor > Show Code Coverage**

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, but in case anyone else runs into this issue:

I also had to turn on "Enable Code Coverage Support" in Build Settings.

[Enable Code Coverage Support screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ahMn.png)

(For clarity, this is from Xcode 7.3.1)